# wordpress hook for widget titles?

Tags: wordpress, filter, hook, widget, action

I need to shorten the widget titles if they're longer than 20 chars, but I don't know what filter/action to use to hook into them.

Is there any? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a filter called [widget_title](http://adambrown.info/p/wp_hooks/hook/widget_title?version=3.0&file=wp-includes/default-widgets.php) you can use. But usually you should be able to change the title of a widget using the backend customization of the widgets.

Comment: Perfect thanks! Yes but it was pretty much a client requirement, I guess for him its easier this way..